# How to set the Transparent statusbar in iphone

Tags: iphone, coding-style, transparent, statusbar

In my application i want to set the statusbar transparent.There are three styles are possible for changing the style of the statusbar.

1. gray
2. black
3. black translucent

mycode:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

How to set the transparent statusbar?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You can only hide the status bar using `Status bar is initially hidden` property in your info.plist

Comment: @max:I want to set the statusbar as transparent ..Thank you

Comment: yes, i know. but it is only possible to hide it or make UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent

Comment: @max:if i'm giving like this ,CODE: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent]; means it makes the statusbar as transparent ah?

Comment: Nope. I makes it translucent (alpha = 0.5). Transparent has alpha = 0.0

Comment: @max:how can i specify the alpha value 0.0 for make statusbar transparent.

Comment: read my answer: it's not possible. status bar has only 3 predefined styles.

Answer (score 12):

The best solution for this problem is to set `self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;` in your view controller and `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` for your status bar.

UPDATE:

As Mihir Oza told in comments the `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent` constant from old version of my answer is now deprecated. Use `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` instead.

Comment: "wantsFullScreenLayout" is critical when using translucent

Comment: 'UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent' is deprecated. use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent.

Comment: setStatusBarStyle was deprecated in iOS 9. Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

Answer (score 2):

For the global app in the `info.plist` add Status bar style: `Transparent Black Style (alpha 0.5)`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is with info.plist. Have a look at [Apple's UIKit pList keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1), specifically `UIStatusBarStyle` (and the value `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent`) for making it translucent, or the UIStatusBarHidden key (for hiding it totally).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make the status bar transparent. There are only 3 possible styles (gray, black and black translucent) you can set and you cannot get the bar's UIView.

However if you have static content behind it (i.e. a fixed part of your UI that you can edit) you can set the status bar to black translucent and add a 50% white layer just behind the bar. This makes the bar appear to be transparent.

Here's an example of what I mean.

[See an example http://cl.ly/7WST/Untitled-1.png](http://cl.ly/7WST/Untitled-1.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. In the info.plist set **status bar style** Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5).
2. In viewcontroller.xib set **size** fullscreen and **status bar** none.
3. In viewcontroller.m add following codes in viewWillAppear:

`self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);`

This worked for me.